# Is there a way to fetch only the first lat lng from an xml file and pass it Calculate and display route function?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, maps

I have been searching for a few days now. I want to display a google map using direction services api. The map works fine as long as I supply origin and destination values within the code as global variables, but when I try to pass it from xml file (after parsing it) to my calculateAndDisplayRoute function, the map does not appear.

pointA is the origin, and first entery of xml file. How can I get it inside downloadUrl function and pass it to calculateAndDisplayRoute function?

**EDIT: So from the comments, I got it how I can fetch the pointA. thank you! Now the problem is The routes are not displayed :( . It displays the routes only when lat lng of pointA are globally initialized.. any thoughts about it?**

downloadUrl and calculateAndDisplayRout are as follows:

```
downloadUrl('http:/localhost/facility/hubs/1.xml', function(data) {


var xml = data.responseXML;
var path = [];
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('result');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {


var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
path.push(point);

waypts.push({
location: point,
stopover: false
})

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: point,
map:map,});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
infoWindow.open(map, marker);});
});

// get route from A to B
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, 
pointB,waypts,waypts1);}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, 
directionsDisplay,pointA, pointB,waypts,waypts1) {
directionsService.route({

    origin: pointA,
   destination:  pointA,
   waypoints: waypts,


   optimizeWaypoints: false,
   avoidTolls: false,
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING


}
```

EDIT: So from the comments, I got it how I can fetch the pointA. thank you!
Now the problem is The routes are not displayed :( . It displays the routes only when lat lng of pointA are globally initialized.. any thoughts about it?

Comment: Probably yes, but i cant read this code, please reformat :)

Comment: @Artur thanks, is it readable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you iterate with a `forEach` when you only want to have the first item of the array? If I understand your question you just have to replace the `forEach` with:

```
// only get first element of array
var markerElem = markers[0];
```

If you'd like to keep the forEach-loop you can do something like this:

```
yourArray.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if (index === 0) {
        var myFirstElement = element;    // this is the first element of the array
        // ...
    } else {
        var myNotFirstElement = element; // this is not the first element of the array
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually need both. First element to pass to calculateAndDisplayRoute function for origin and rest of the elements to pass to calculateAndDisplayRoute function as waypoints.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can also check the index within the `forEach` Loop, as described in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: I extended my answer with an other example to keep the forEach loop.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! But there is another problem, The routes are not displayed :( . It displays the routes only when lat lng of pointA are globally initialized..  any thoughts about it?